# Git : pulling from repo [I had to recreate some files again]

Tags: git, codeigniter, centos

I'm using git to transfer files between test server and live server. 
first i used to commit updates from test to the repo (Master) then pull updated from repo(Master) to live server then the whole live website down and when i try to edit any controller or any file i can not do that although the files have the same permissions.all what i can do is deleting the file and create it again with the same content.

can any one help me . thanks

Comment: Check latest commit hash that was before last update and use `git fetch <repo> <commit>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using codeigniter, you may be modifying config files which should be put inside git .ignore to avoid overwriting them when you are deploying the latest changes.